# Shadowbox Firefox incompatibility issue with scrollbars

Tags: css, cross-browser, shadowbox

Shadowbox in Firefox always shows me the scrollbars; With Chrome, IE and Safari works OK. Any one knows how to solve this problem? I tried different things in the shadowbox.css but nothing  work.

[image: Shadowbox Scroll Problem]

**shadowbox.css**

```
#sb-title-inner,#sb-info-inner,#sb-loading-inner,div.sb-message{font-family:"HelveticaNeue-Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:200;color:#fff}
#sb-container{position:fixed;margin:0;padding:0;top:0;left:0;z-index:999;text-align:left;visibility:hidden;display:none}
#sb-overlay{position:relative;height:100%;width:100%;}
#sb-wrapper{position:absolute;visibility:hidden;width:100px;}
#sb-wrapper-inner{position:relative;border:0px solid #303030;overflow:hidden;height:100px;}
#sb-body{position:relative;height:100%;}
#sb-body-inner{position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;}
#sb-player.html{height:100%;overflow:visible;}
#sb-body img{border:none;}
#sb-loading{position:relative;height:100%;}
#sb-loading-inner{position:absolute;font-size:14px;line-height:24px;height:24px;top:50%;margin-top:-12px;width:100%;text-align:center;}
#sb-loading-inner span{background:url(loading.gif) no-repeat;padding-left:34px;display:inline-block;}
#sb-body,#sb-loading{background-color: ;}
#sb-title,#sb-info{position:relative;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;}
#sb-title,#sb-title-inner{height:26px;line-height:26px;}
#sb-title-inner{font-size:16px;}
#sb-info,#sb-info-inner{height:20px;line-height:20px;}
#sb-info-inner{font-size:12px;}
#sb-nav{float:right;height:16px;padding:2px 0;width:45%;}
#sb-nav a{display:block;float:right;height:16px;width:16px;margin-left:3px;cursor:pointer;background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#sb-nav-close{background-image:url(close.png); visibility:hidden;}
#sb-nav-next{background-image:url(next.png);}
#sb-nav-previous{background-image:url(previous.png);}
#sb-nav-play{background-image:url(play.png);}
#sb-nav-pause{background-image:url(pause.png);}
#sb-counter{float:left;width:45%;}
#sb-counter a{padding:0 4px 0 0;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;color:#fff;}
#sb-counter a.sb-counter-current{text-decoration:underline;}
div.sb-message{font-size:12px;padding:10px;text-align:center;}
div.sb-message a:link,div.sb-message a:visited{color:#fff;text-decoration:underline;}
```

The site where resides the shadowbox iframe is ([http://www.miradorhotel.com.co](http://miradorhotel.com.co)). when you enter the site it automatically pops up.

Comment: Can you give a link? Hard to debug code without...code :)

Comment: There i add the shadowbox.css that i have.

Comment: That looks like the default css that ships with shadowbox, which doesn't have this problem out of the box. More than likely it's something else (css inheritance if I had to guess) that's interfering with it, but without a *link* or all of your code it's impossible to tell.

Comment: I edit the post with the URL where the problem resides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. The easiest solution is to change your iframe so that scrolling="no" to get rid of the scrollbars.

If you're worried about users on smaller screens, change both the iframe and the table inside it to use fixed sizes instead of percentages, then set scrolling="no" as previously mentioned.

Comment: What you said worked. There is no scrolls, but the thing is if a user with small resoluion enters the page. Weird that this is a Firefox problem that only happens to me. Thanks anyway, is best no scrolls that scrolls all the time.

Comment: Maybe if you clean up the errors on the iframe page your using for Shadowbox things will work in Firefox. Review the errors [here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmiradorhotel.com.co%2Fver_promocion.php%3Fid%3D3&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3). In particular, you have script tag after the closing html tag.